# hasMany association not found

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

My user has many exams.

User:

```
Ext.define('Tm.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        hasMany: { model: 'Tm.model.Exam', name: 'exams' },

        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'username', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'email', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'nameFirst', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'nameLast', type: 'string' }
        ],

                ...
    }
});
```

Exam:

```
Ext.define('Tm.model.Exam', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        belongsTo: 'Tm.model.User',

        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int', defaultValue: null },
            { name: 'title', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'Exam' }
        ],

                ...
    }
});
```

Calling `var exams = user.exams();` gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exams'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must require your associated model for the getter to be generated.

So add this to the definition of `Tm.model.User`:

```
requires: ['Tm.model.Exam']
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish Sencha can write their docs properly or give better error reporting. Why isn't it necessary on a `belongsTo` association?

Comment: I found that by test & try. Now, I've just looked into the code and in fact what you really need is to have all your models required, anywhere in the code (not necessarily in the owner model definition, nor before it). The creation of associations to models not loaded yet are deferred until it is loaded (but Ext doesn't trigger it itself). That's a clever way to prevent circular dependencies, because an "incomplete" model can be defined and used by others to resolve their own associations. But you're right, the doc could insist on the fact that associated model won't be loaded automatically.

Comment: To sum this long comment up, it is also required for `belongsTo` associations that the target model be required. It is simply less likely to forget to require a parent model...